# Отсутствует перевод пояснения при ожидающемся утверждении правки в очереди проверок

Tags: дефект, локализация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На traducir перевод уже предложен (видимо давно, я уже не помню когда его добавил): https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17003